# die function for removing event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I created a `mouseover` event handler like this:

```
$('.grpName_tooltip0, .grpName_tooltip1, .grpName_tooltip2').live('mouseover',function(){
    var localGrpName=$(this).attr('class')=='grpName_tooltip0'?arrGrpNames[0]:$(this).attr('class')=='grpName_tooltip1'?arrGrpNames[1]:$(this).attr('class')=='grpName_tooltip2'?arrGrpNames[2]:'';
    $('#GroupsDivTooltip').html(localGrpName);
    $('.ttpGrp').css({'top':$(this).offset().top+27,'left':$(this).offset().left}).fadeIn();
}).live('mouseleave',function(){
    $('#GroupsDivTooltip').html('');
    $('.ttpGrp').fadeOut();
});
```

I want to do .die for particular `.grpName_tooltip0` class name.

When I tried individually like below is not working...

```
$('.grpName_tooltip0').die('mouseover');
```

It is working for all mentioned... like below

```
$('.grpName_tooltip0, .grpName_tooltip1, .grpName_tooltip2').die('mouseover');
```

I just want to only for one.

Please suggest me.....

Comment: It's not possible to *remove* the event handler, since there is only *one* event handler attached to the document which always fires if the selector is matched. Note from the documentation: *"In order for `.die()` to function correctly, the selector used with it must match exactly the selector initially used with `.live()`."*.

Answer (score 3):

First: `.live()` and `.die()` are deprecated since jQuery 1.7. You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) now (but that exhibits the same problems, so all the solutions here are still valid).

---

If you don't have to use event delegation, you can simply `unbind` the event handler [like @Raminson showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383470/218196).

If you have to use event delegation, one way is to add an additional event handler directly to the element, which prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM and triggering the event handler at the root ([like @Farhad showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383459/218196)).

An other workaround could be to set a flag on the element, and only execute the event the event handler if the flag is not, e.g., `false`:

```
$('.grpName_tooltip0, .grpName_tooltip1, .grpName_tooltip2').live('mouseover',function(){
    if($(this).data('active') !== false) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

You can then enable and disable the event handler for the elements by setting

```
$('.grpName_tooltip0').data('active', false); // or true
```

---

All the above approaches have the disadvantage that in order prevent the event handler from firing, the element must exist at the moment you are making the decision. This might not be the case in your situation though.

Therefore, yet an other way could be to keep a list of selectors which you want to exclude from the event handler:

```
var exclude = [];

$('.grpName_tooltip0, .grpName_tooltip1, .grpName_tooltip2').live('mouseover',function(){
    var run = true, $self = $(this);
    $.each(exclude, function(sel) {
        if($self.is(sel)) {
            run = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(run) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Then all you have to do is add the selector you don't want the handler to fire for to the list:

```
exclude.push('.grpName_tooltip0');
```

This approach can be optimized in various ways (e.g. using an object instead of an array for `O(1)` access), depending on your actual situation.

One more way would be to unbind the event handler completely and only rebind it for the elements you want it:

```
function handler() {
    // your event handler code here
}

var selectors = ['.grpName_tooltip0', '.grpName_tooltip1', '.grpName_tooltip2'];

$(selectors.join()).live('mouseover', handler);
```

Later:

```
$(selectors.join()).die('mouseover');
$($.grep(selectors, function(sel) {
    return sel !==  '.grpName_tooltip0';
}).join()).live('mouseover', handler);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will be better to try this:

```
$('.grpName_tooltip0').mouseover(function(){return false;});
```

Comment: Or shorter: `$('.grpName_tooltip0').mouseover(false);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.grpName_tooltip0, .grpName_tooltip1, .grpName_tooltip2').mouseenter(function(){
   ....
   $('.grpName_tooltip0').unbind('mouseenter');
})
```

Comment: That does not use event delegation though, it might not be applicable to the OP's use case.